# Slow query log is logging faster queries in log file

Tags: mysql

I've setup MySQL slow query log on my database server and set the long query time to 5. 
Just checked the log and its logging queries that take only milliseconds. Anyone know why that would be? Here's some of the log.

```
I am using mysql sloq query log and set the following line in my.cnf file:
slow_query_log=1
long_query_time=5
log-output=FILE
log-queries-not-using-indexes

but my log file show like :

# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 0.077108  Lock_time: 0.000042 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 292
SET timestamp=1389868398;
UPDATE `cp_sessions` SET `last_activity` = 1389868398 WHERE session_id = 'e9f397b37812e7e5b0563de6a32d181b';
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 0.022188  Lock_time: 0.000072 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 292
SET timestamp=1389868398;
UPDATE `cp_sessions` SET `last_activity` = 1389868398, `user_id` = NULL, `user_data` = 'a:3:{s:9:\"game_name\";s:5:\"poker\";s:3:\"utm\";N;s:5:\"url_1\";s:23:\"http://adda52merge.org/\";}' WHERE `session_id` = 'e9f397b37812e7e5b0563de6a32d181b';
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 0.000465  Lock_time: 0.000068 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 292
SET timestamp=1389868398;
SELECT *
FROM (`cp_sessions`)
WHERE `session_id` = '8c34926f9f6d711bdc14eeeb40b7db7b'
AND `ip_address` = '192.168.1.235'
AND `user_agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko';
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 0.033085  Lock_time: 0.000036 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 292
SET timestamp=1389868398;
UPDATE `cp_sessions` SET `last_activity` = 1389868398 WHERE session_id = '8c34926f9f6d711bdc14eeeb40b7db7b';
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 0.000350  Lock_time: 0.000055 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 292
SET timestamp=1389868398;
SELECT *
FROM (`cp_sessions`)
WHERE `session_id` = '8c34926f9f6d711bdc14eeeb40b7db7b';
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 0.031274  Lock_time: 0.000043 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 292
SET timestamp=1389868398;
UPDATE `cp_sessions` SET `login_attempt` = 0 WHERE `session_id` = '8c34926f9f6d711bdc14eeeb40b7db7b';
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 0.000298  Lock_time: 0.000029 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 292
SET timestamp=1389868398;
SELECT *
FROM (`cp_sessions`)
WHERE `user_id` = '113';
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 0.000479  Lock_time: 0.000080 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 292
SET timestamp=1389868398;
SELECT *
FROM (`cp_sessions`)
WHERE `session_id` = '4809d7eef185f2bf3d8e38e1858a637c'
AND `ip_address` = '192.168.1.235'
AND `user_agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko';
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 0.022236  Lock_time: 0.000037 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 292
SET timestamp=1389868398;
UPDATE `cp_sessions` SET `user_data` = '', `user_id` = 0 WHERE `user_id` = '113';
```

Please help me where I am wrong and what can i do for this slow query log
I want to execute that query which take more time for execution.

Answer (score 2):

The setting `log-queries-not-using-indexes` will add any query that is not using indexes to the slow log.

This should be activated as it can easily help you optimize your queries.

If you want queries over a certain amount of seconds you can execute

`SELECT * FROM mysql.slow_log WHERE query_time > 5`

This will give queries with execution time over 5 seconds.

Comment: where is put on this query?

Comment: i want to check which query are give slow execution for multiple userlogin . so how can i checked..?

Comment: Use `IN` in the `WHERE` clause. Like `WHERE user_host IN ('root[root] @ localhost []','the other usename etc')`

Comment: What extacly do you want because you didnt mention anything about certain users in your question.,

Comment: actually i want to check which query are slow in my log file . when i am not  using "log-queries-not-using-indexes" then my log are not created. but when I am using  above statement with "log-queries-not-using-indexes" in my.cnf file then my log are showing above result..I am login multiple user using JMeter load testing. that why i am checking my log file